# How to compare ids that are inside of plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, plugins

I'm looking for solutions to compare the `id` elements inside of the Plugin. This is the code that has a problem:

```
(function($, window, undefined) {
  $.fn.thePlugin = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      const $el = $(this);
      console.log($el);
      if ($el == $('#bird')) {
        console.log($el + ' is a bird.');
        // $el == document.getElementById('bird')
        // $el == document.getElementById('bird').id didn't work.
      } else if ($el == $('#superman')) {
        console.log($el + ' is Superman');
      }
    })
  }
}(jQuery));

$('#bird').thePlugin();
$('#superman').thePlugin();
```

> w.fn.init [div#bird]
>   w.fn.init [div#superman]

Apparently, the `console.logs` which are inside of `if statement` doesn't firing up. Only 1 log fires up that is outside of the `if statement`.

I've tested 2 ways for solving this problem, using jQuery selectors and without using jQuery selectors but all of the ways didn't work.

Are there any ways to compare the `id` inside of the plugin structure?

- I cannot use `getElementByClassName` because my DOM style is always starting with `id` something like this:

  ```
  #section {
    .container {
      .grid {
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to compare the id of the elements, you can use the following, by comparing only the string value of the id:

```
if ($el.id === 'bird') {
   console.log($el + ' is a bird.');
}
```

The reason that your code doesn't work is that you are trying to compare two objects, that have different references in the memory. Example:

const variableOne = {
    key: 1
}

const variableTwo = {
    key: 1
}

variableOne == variableTwo // Resolves to false

If you need to compare that two elements are the same, by using the $el variable, you can use the following:

```
if ($el.is($('#bird')) {
    console.log($el + ' is a bird.');
}
```

See the following link for `is` function documentation
http://api.jquery.com/is/

You can also find more info about the `Object.is` function and how to compare objects in javascript here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Comment: Simple, clear and memorable. Thank you for answering.